# ASP.NET Pop up page_load multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, fancybox, pageload

I am working on ASP.NET webform development. I am working with jquery fancybox to call my webpage as a popup window. Everything is working fine. But my issue comes up when I close my pop-up window and open the same page as a pop-up again, the page_load is calling multiple times.

Example:  I have a button "Add User". When I click first time, it opens the pop-up and Page_load is called once. I closed the pop-up window and again click on "Add User", this time when I run Debug, it loading Page_Load method twice and again thrice and so on.

On my master page I am calling the fancybox api (Because I will be using Fancybox in my whole application)

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(FancyBoxLoad);

function FancyBoxLoad(sender, args) {   
     var dWidth = parseInt(500);var dHeight = parseInt(500);
                $(".various").click(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr('href').match(/width=[0-9]+/i) != null) {
                        dWidth = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=', ''));
                        dHeight = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/height=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('height=', ''));
                    }

                    $(".various").fancybox({
                        maxWidth: dWidth,
                        maxHeight: dHeight,
                        fitToView: true,
                        width: '75%',
                        height: '100%',
                        autoSize: false,
                        closeClick: false,
                        openEffect: 'none',
                        closeEffect: 'none'                    
                    });
                });
            }
```

On my Content page I have

```
 <div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;">
      <a id="addnew" class="various fancybox.iframe" href="">
  <input class="button" value="Add User" type="button" /></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add your page_load function to the question

Comment: There is nothing in my Page_Load()